# I can't compare for cause Double Data binding Angular5

Tags: angular5

I can't compare 2 array because when my User changes something , automatically this changes in 2 array, then I can't compare ...

I tried with create new Object () but This doesn't run ...

```
  this.service.data().subscribe(
         data => {
            this.params = new Object(data);
            this.originalParams = new Object(data);
```

Here data.validated is false ->

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of params">
 <input type="checkbox" id="{{data.id}}" name="{{data.id}}" [(ngModel)]="data.validated" [disabled]="enableValidation(data.commentary)">
```

[image]

Then I changed this checkbox a True and I do click in save for compare ->

```
  console.log("formParams" , formParams);
  console.log("originalParams" , originalParams);
```

result ->

[image]

I can't compare ...

I have 10 checkbox I only need send the different results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this example can resolve your reference issue

```
this.service.data().subscribe(
     data => {
        this.params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        this.originalParams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
     }
);
```

Stringify js object and parse will recreate an object with out reference link. I hope it will help you